# Is Stack Overflow losing its guidelines concerning answering low-quality questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, blog, welcoming

A couple of days ago, Jay Hanson published a blog post titled [*Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) Although I have several questions about things said in the post, this paragraph jumped out at me:

> And little makes me sadder than comments on answers saying, “Don’t answer questions like this – it encourages them.” Now, some questions are off-topic. [...] But it’s totally cool to answer questions without giving a grilled poop sandwich about exactly what’s allowed. It’s fine to volunteer in one way without being expected to read and enforce every rule and meta discussion since forever.

The reason the above statement jumped out at me, was because the statement Jay says saddens him, is the statement I often use when trying to politely inform other users that we shouldn't answer low-quality questions. My understanding after participating on Stack Overflow for almost two years now, it that generally low quality questions should avoid being answered. And one of the reasons why is because it gives the impression that Stack Overflow welcomes these kinds of questions, which I'm sure we don't. On top of this, the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) also [recommends to avoid answering bad questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

To be clear here, I want to define "low-quality". By saying "low-quality", I'm not referring to questions that have poor formating, or questions that have grammatical/spelling errors. I'm talking about questions that have no MCVE, are poorly researched, code dumps, etc.

I understand that users don't and shouldn't always have to be robots, strictly following every rule, all the time. But the above paragraph's use of "exactly" feels like a slippery slope to me. What kind of posts are allowed that don't "exactly" follow the quality control rules? Perhaps "exactly" should be more explicitly defined?

Although I admit I may be over-stating what Jay is saying above, is Stack Overflow now saying that it's fine to answer questions that would traditionally be considered low-quality and worthy of closing?

Comment: I presume you do mean *"loosing"* and not *"losing"*. But perhaps use *loosening* instead?